# What does 相比起来则 in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I try to fine the grammar for this sentence:

Noun 1 + 比 + Noun 2 + Adj. + 很多 (Expressing "much more" in comparisons)

But in not the same as:
玛丽**相比起来则**温和+得多.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a complementary sentence to understand this better.

Let’s say “Daniel is very fierce.”

> 丹尼尔很凶。

With the context that Daniel is fierce, you can then compare Mary’s temperament using the grammatical structure you have shown.

相比起来则 comprises 相比起来 + 则.

相比起来 means “when you compare (Mary and Daniel)”

则 is a word which performs the function of “then, thus, therefore”.

You can then read the sentence as “Compared to Daniel, Mary is much milder.”

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. I understand more clearly now but why 起来 use after 相比?

Comment: It’s to show “completion” of your action